# Is it idiomatic to use "it is just that" for adding an extra point to what one just mentioned?

Tags: phrase-choice, idiomatic-language

"it is just that" is usually used as a polite way to disagree with what other says, or to politely say no to a request.

Is it idiomatic that one uses it for adding an extra point to what one just mentioned.

Example:

> Group A require intentionality for moral act, group B don't. So the
>   act described here is moral according to both A's and B's view. **It is
>   just that** "intentional moral act" is not a proper term in the view of group A, because in their view there is no such thing as "unintentional moral
>   act".

Is "it is just that" used idiomatically in the above sentence. If not, what to use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely idiomatic, and will help you sound more like a native speaker. Note that you're better off using the contracted form:

> It's just that ...

Also note that it does not have to introduce a disagreement. The idiom can make a positive assertion.

> I don't know why I'm humming tunes today. It's just that I feel so good.

Comment: But I would not use it in a report, or essay. It's really more appropriate to spoken English. In that context, I would use "but" or "however" (or, if it was not opposing what came before, "indeed" or "furthermore".).

Answer (score 1):

***[It was s just that](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/its-just-that)*** :

> You use the expression it's just that when you are making a complaint, suggestion, or excuse, so that the person you are talking to will not get annoyed with you.
>
> - *I'm sorry I struck you. I didn't mean to. It's just that I was so mad.
>     Your hair is all right; it's just that you need a haircut.*

(Collins Dictionary)

It is used also to suggest something, as in the sentence you are asking about.